# OTC derivatives trade life cycle

Tags: derivatives, trading

Can someone please walk through a typical OTC derivative trade life cycle? Or could you please provide a good source on that topic? ( I mean things like negotiation - trade execution - trade capture, etc .)

Comment: @AlexC thank you very much for your comment. That makes sense. But when I said OTC derivatives lifecycle, i meant things like negotiation - trade execution - trade capture etc

Comment: OK, my mistake.

Comment: @AlexC do you know the trade lifecycle that you could explain plz?